# Perforce changing the default editor

Tags: perforce

I use perforce for my revision control, when I hit 'p4 change' it always opens up the list on emacs, and we all know the pain of deleting text in it. How do i change it to gedit or vim or anything else? My default text editor is gedit.

Comment: This has nothing to with Emacs. I'm removing the tag and adding `p4`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

On the command line, set P4EDITOR either as an environment variable or in the P4CONFIG file.

Comment: That's the variable. I'd be surprised if it didn't respect EDITOR too though.

Comment: Perforce will respect EDITOR if P4EDITOR is unset.

Answer (score 8):

From the command line,

> p4 set P4EDITOR="C:\File Editor\editor.exe"

You can test that this was successfull by running the following command after, which should launch your desired editor.

> p4 workspace

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem on my Windows system.
It always used to open clumsy notepad.
I am more comfortable with `TextPad`, so to change default perforce editor, I made following changes:
I opened System Properties and added new environment variable as following:

```
Name: `P4EDITOR` 
Value: `C:\Program Files (x86)\TextPad 4\TextPad.exe`
```

After that open a new `CMD` and there you go !!!

Answer (score 4):

For Notepad++ I needed to use this command `-multiInst` to trigger edits.

```
p4 set P4EDITOR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe -multiInst"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `EDITOR` environment variable. Also, the command line `p4` should have an option to specify an editor. Also, the `.p4config` file might have something as well.

Answer (score 0):

Also need to check if EDITOR/P4EDITOR path is correct. If path is wrong, perforce will choose previously working editor.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of WSL, likely your `p4` binary is provided for Windows platform as the path and operations are most compatible there, so it's `p4.exe` most likely. Then simple wawy of setting editor in `P4EDITOR` is not just enough, we have to convert input argument of filepath which is provided in Windows-based into Linux path.

[This](https://perforce-user.perforce.narkive.com/BKU5iAfe/p4-cygwin-and-windows-paths#post2) solution dated back 19 years ago still works

The concept is to

- Create a bash/shell script that accept the argument.
- Then in the script we can use `wslpath $1` to convert Windows path into Linux path.
- The script can be just

```
#!/bin/bash
vim `wslpath $1`
```

I thought I might not be able to use Vim to edit change, or client spec of perforce and have to end up using whatever provided like Notepad (not against it, but I just want to use Vim). This solution works for me.